# How to add buttons from a dictionary but only if the dictionary states it's enabled?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm building a drink dispenser using a Raspberry Pi and using Kivy to build the UI.
I want to only show available drinks on the home screen if the pump for each of the ingredients needed is "enabled". If any of the ingredients needed to make the drink are assigned to a pump that's not enabled then I don't want that drink's button to be created. In short, only the drinks that have all required ingredients "Enabled: True" should be displayed. Being new to both python and kivy I can't find a way to do this. Here's what I have so far...

main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.clock import *

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '480')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '800')
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'dock')
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import *
from kivy.uix.button import *
from kivy.uix.label import *
from kivy.clock import *

pinList = [11, 13, 15, 19, 21, 23, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 38, 36, 32, 26, 24]

drink_list = {'Rum & Pepsi': {'ingredients': {'Rum': 50, 'Pepsi': 100}},
              'Cherry Pepsi': {'ingredients': {'Cherry syrup': 40, 'Pepsi': 150}},
              'Lemon Pepsi': {'ingredients': {'Lemon Syrup': 10, 'Pepsi': 113}}}

test_list = {
    'Pump 1': {'Pin': [11], 'Ingredient': ['Pepsi'], 'Pumptime': [0.15], 'Enabled': [True]},
    'Pump 2': {'Pin': [13], 'Ingredient': ['Rum'], 'Pumptime': [0.15], 'Enabled': [True]},
    'Pump 3': {'Pin': [15], 'Ingredient': ['Cherry syrup'], 'Pumptime': [0.15], 'Enabled': [True]},
    'Pump 4': {'Pin': [19], 'Ingredient': ['Lemon syrup'], 'Pumptime': [0.15], 'Enabled': [True]},
    'Pump 5': {'Pin': [21], 'Ingredient': ['Unused'], 'Pumptime': [0.15], 'Enabled': [True]},
    'Pump 6': {'Pin': [23], 'Ingredient': ['Unused'], 'Pumptime': [0.15], 'Enabled': [True]},
    'Pump 7': {'Pin': [29], 'Ingredient': ['Unused'], 'Pumptime': [0.15], 'Enabled': [True]},
    'Pump 8': {'Pin': [31], 'Ingredient': ['Unused'], 'Pumptime': [0.15], 'Enabled': [True]},
    'Pump 9': {'Pin': [33], 'Ingredient': ['Unused'], 'Pumptime': [0.15], 'Enabled': [True]},
    'Pump 10': {'Pin': [35], 'Ingredient': ['Unused'], 'Pumptime': [0.15], 'Enabled': [True]},
    'Pump 11': {'Pin': [37], 'Ingredient': ['Unused'], 'Pumptime': [0.15], 'Enabled': [True]},
    'Pump 12': {'Pin': [38], 'Ingredient': ['Unused'], 'Pumptime': [0.15], 'Enabled': [True]},
    'Pump 13': {'Pin': [36], 'Ingredient': ['Unused'], 'Pumptime': [0.15], 'Enabled': [True]},
    'Pump 14': {'Pin': [32], 'Ingredient': ['Unused'], 'Pumptime': [0.15], 'Enabled': [True]},
    'Pump 15': {'Pin': [26], 'Ingredient': ['Unused'], 'Pumptime': [0.15], 'Enabled': [True]},
    'Pump 16': {'Pin': [24], 'Ingredient': ['Unused'], 'Pumptime': [0.15], 'Enabled': [True]}
}

class HomeScreen(Screen):

    @mainthread
    def on_enter(self):

        # add drink buttons (only if needed pumps are enabled)
        for drink in drink_list:
            ingredients_needed = [*(drink_list[drink]['ingredients'])]
            for x in ingredients_needed:
                for pump in test_list.keys():
                    if x in test_list[pump]['Ingredient'] and test_list[pump]['Enabled'] == [True]:
                        print('yes')
                        button = Button(text=drink, size_hint=(None, None))
                        self.ids.grid1.add_widget(button)
                    else:
                        pass


        # add settings button
        button = Button(text='Settings Page', size_hint=(None, None))
        button.bind(on_press=self.go_first_screen)
        self.ids.grid1.add_widget(button)

    def go_first_screen(self, event):
        self.manager.current = 'settings_screen'


class SettingsScreen(Screen):

    @mainthread
    def on_enter(self):
        # Drink Manager Tab
        for drink in drink_list:
            drink_buttons = Button(text=str(drink), size_hint=(None, None))
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(drink_buttons)
        btn = Button(text='Change Screen', size_hint=(None, None))
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(btn)

        # Pump Assignment Tab
        for pump in test_list:
            pump_buttons = Button(text=str(pump) + ' - \n ' + str(*test_list[pump]['Ingredient']), size_hint=(None, None))
            self.ids.pump_grid.add_widget(pump_buttons)

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        self.ids.grid.clear_widgets()


class Test(App):
    pass


Test().run()
```

test.kv...

```
#:kivy 1.9.0
ScreenManager:
    HomeScreen:
    SettingsScreen:

<HomeScreen>:
    name: 'home_screen'

    StackLayout:
        id: grid1
        orientation: 'lr-tb'
        padding: 10
        spacing: 5

<SettingsScreen>:
    name: 'settings_screen'

    TabbedPanel:
        do_default_tab: False
        tab_pos: 'top_mid'
        tab_height: 70
        tab_width: self.width/3
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'Drink Manager'

            StackLayout:
                id: grid
                orientation: 'lr-tb'
                padding: 10
                spacing: 10

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'Pump Assignment'

            StackLayout:
                id: pump_grid
                orientation: 'lr-tb'
                padding: 15
                spacing: 15
```

Currently it's creating 2 buttons for each drink (except the lemon one for some reason?) where I only need 1 button for each drink:
[image]

Comment: Can you please be more specific as to the problem you're encountering with your program? Most of your code looks OK, however while I don't know `kivy`, it looks weird to me that you're not using any of your `Screen` subclasses in the `Test` class, so you're effectively just running the default `App` class which probably doesn't do anything useful. Looking at [this](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#basic-usage) I'm guessing `Test` needs to override the `build` method and return a `ScreenManager` instance with instances of your `Screen` subclasses added.

Comment: I have added a bit more info to the question. The app, screens etc are all working as they should I just need a point in the right direction in regards to only adding the button for drinks whos ingredients are available. This way if I run out of any ingredients I can just set the pump to "Enabled: False" and any drinks that use the out of stock ingredient will automatically be removed from the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why you're currently getting duplicate buttons

I've added a `print` statement where the button should be created, executed the code and witnessed the following result:

```
drink=Rum & Pepsi, x=Rum, pump=Pump 2
drink=Rum & Pepsi, x=Pepsi, pump=Pump 1
drink=Cherry Pepsi, x=Cherry syrup, pump=Pump 3
drink=Cherry Pepsi, x=Pepsi, pump=Pump 1
drink=Lemon Pepsi, x=Lemon Syrup, pump=[no pump]
drink=Lemon Pepsi, x=Pepsi, pump=Pump 1
```

this shows that you're creating the button for every ingredient in the drink. Additionally, for Lemon Pepsi you're not finding the "Lemon syrup" pump because in `drink_list` `Syrup` is upper case.

#### How to fix it

For example like this:

```py
class HomeScreen(Screen):

    @mainthread
    def on_enter(self):

        # either define this function here, or at module level,
        # or as a @staticmethod in this class
        def _get_pump_by_ingredient(ingredient):
            for name, pump in test_list.items():
                if pump["Ingredient"] == [ingredient]:
                    return pump

        for drink in drink_list:
            ingredients_needed = [*(drink_list[drink]['ingredients'])]
            if all(_get_pump_by_ingredient(item)["Enabled"] == [True]
                   for item
                   in ingredients_needed):
                  print('yes')
                  button = Button(text=drink, size_hint=(None, None))
                  self.ids.grid1.add_widget(button)

        # add settings button
        ...
```

Note that the above code will throw an exception if a pump cannot be found (like with the "Lemon Syrup") but that might be a good thing.

#### Some more feedback

- it might make sense to create a `Pump` class because `dict`s are awkward at this level of complexity
- it's kind of weird how you're putting a lot of things into single-element lists (`'Pumptime': [0.15]` instead of just `'Pumptime': 0.15`)